# Load site in firefox when use selenium web driver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My default browser is firefox. But when I trying to load a file using selenium web driver it automatically load through google Chrome. How can I change it to firefox? Eclipse preferences also has set to default browser.

```
    package com.selenium.example;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

    public class ExampleSelenium {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://localhost:3030/fuseki.html");
}}
```

Comment: if you write this  FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); then it must open in firefox.

Comment: @HelpingHands That didn't happen. That's the problem with me. It always loaded through google chrome. I has changed proxy setting in google chrome. Therefor that doesn't support to local host. So I want to load localhost through firefox.

Comment: what if you use other URL? instead of localhost? like google.com ? is that open in firefox?

Comment: @HelpingHands Yes. Firefox.

Comment: Then its localhost issue I think..try using method driver.Navigate().GoToURL()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66480/discussion-between-helping-hands-and-maduri).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please user below method to get URL :

```
 driver.getUrl("Your host link");
```